# I don't understand this sentence

Tags: meaning

I don't quite understand this part

> "Poitras, who profiled another celebrated data warrior, Edward Snowden, in Citizenfour, filmed with Assange from 2010-2012"

The commas are confusing. I know that "Edward" links to the celebrated data warrior but I am confused with which part "in Citizenfour" links to and the part after it. Please give a thorough explanation of the entire sentence which tells the connections between different parts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You have nested parenthetical expressions: the inner pair of commas enclose "Edward Snowden" (related to "celebrated data warrior"), and the outer pair enclose "who profiled ... in Citizenfour" (related to "Poitras").

Comment: Is this the caption for a photograph or film clip?  If so, the photo provides extra context to the sentence, which otherwise would need to carry itself better.  As a photo caption, it's fine: there is an assumed "This is..." at the start.

Answer (score 2):

This is the basic sentence:

> Poitras filmed with Assange from 2010-2012

The rest of the stuff is parenthetical:

> Poitras (who profiled another celebrated data warrior (Edward Snowden)(in Citizenfour)) filmed with Assange from 2010-2012

Pairs of commas are often used to mark out parenthetical elements.

I don't think it's a great sentence. This is my attempt to improve it:

> Poitras, who would go on to profile another data warrior, Edward Snowden, later in *Citizenfour*, filmed with Assange from 2010-2012.

Comment: I would parse it as *Poitras (who profiled another celebrated data warrior (Edward Snowden) in Citizenfour) filmed with Assange from 2010-2012*. The comma after *Edward Snowden* just marks the end of the apposition. *in citizenfour* is just an integral part of the relative sentence, not another parenthetical expression. (That is just an interpretation; the commas are compatible with either parsing.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider, yes, actually now that you have pointed it out, I think your version is probably what the writer intended.